# QGIS Print/export quality is bad (from bitmap/tiles - to PNG/PDF)

Tags: export

To me, this looks like the exported bitmap is scaled from another zoom-level, than optimal - which is used for preview.
-exporting to PNG does not help (so it is not a compression issue)

[image: To the left, preview - to the right is the exported PDF/PNG]

Decent quality screenshots: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yixbiXm7AvJyCHgobMJVRmJobSpt4Xuz?usp=sharing

How can I make the export be as good as the preview? /can I force it to use some other/appropriate zoom level for generating the data?

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: How can I make the export be as good as the preview?  /can I force it to use some other/appropriate zoom level for generating the data?

Comment: I can't compare the images, because they don't show the same area. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I could pan the area, but please just observe the artifacts on the text. One of the screenshots are of almost same area.
stackexchange did not allow decent quality (file size) - please see:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yixbiXm7AvJyCHgobMJVRmJobSpt4Xuz?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide details on how you export, as well as data sources and what you understand to be "decent quality". How does your desired DPI relate to the source DPI?

Comment: there is no "source DPI", - but clearly - I can zoom in the source (.mbiles) to beyond usable level, and see undistorted text.   preview of anything higher than 200dpi is nice, increasing above 400dpi makes barely any difference.   setting 600dpi is what I did - the map source is clearly able to provide nice details (as seen in the preview)
Only the export is ... somehow made bad - and I do not understand why. 
My best guess is that the export grabs wrong zoom-level, and attempt to scale it.

Comment: Your last comment is probably the right answer : the tiles are usually made for screen display so have a pretty low resolution, when exporting QGIS fetch more tile and resize then to match the higher  export resolution. (if you export in a different projection than the tile reprojection will also degrade quality)

Comment: if it can render the data at a certain density on the screen (like 200m per 1cm)  - I see no reason not to expect it to be printed with the same quality. 
Also:  Let's forget DPI and printing.  The preview is perfectly fine - why is it impossible to export the preview to .png without quality loss ?